# MIME::Lite and the Message-ID

Tags: perl, mime-message

When using [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME%3a%3aLite) is there a way to get the Message-ID assigned by the MTA when the message is accepted?  Here's my code snippet.

```
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From    => $from_address,
    To      => $recipient,
    Bcc     => $recipient,
    Subject => $subject,
    Type    => 'text/html',
    Data    => $text);

$status = $msg->send();
```

I've tried setting `Debug=>1` in the `$msg->send` command but `$status` does not contain the Message-ID nor does the debug output have it.

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 1):

No. If you want to know the message ID, you can try setting one yourself, and then checking if your MTA uses it, or overwrites it.

Comment: You can also BCC yourself to get the MTA-modified version.  But most MTAs simply don't report the Message-ID during the SMTP session, so those are your only 2 choices.

Comment: Yep, tried that setting it myself.  The MTA overwrites it.  I found using a Socket script and doing the SMTP protocol myself the MTA does report the Message-ID when accepting the message, eg 250 Message received: 20120809235621@myserver.net.  I was just hoping to use MIME::Lite instead of my script.  Thanks.